# activate readonly back after editing the input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i activate the readonly back after finishing the edit of the input ?

this is my code for now :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("input").bind('click focus', function(){
                $('input').each(function(){
                        $(this).attr("readonly", false);
                        });
                });
         });
</script>
```

an input like this :

```
<input type="text"  class="m" readonly="readonly" id="anchor_text">
```

i think something with focusout, i need to put readonly back when i go to the next input, so the edited input can't be change unless i hit again click on it.

Comment: $(this).removeAttr("readonly");

Comment: Do you want it do be read-only, but that user can edit it at the same time? Can you explain what you try to achieve here?

Comment: i want to remove when i click out of the input or tab, not remove it for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$("input").bind('click focus', function(){
     $(this).attr("readonly", false);
  }).bind('blur', function(){
     $(this).attr("readonly", true);
 });​
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/DkCvu/1/

Comment: @Abude You should probably do only this. Setting to readonly initially might make the wrong impression on the user.

Comment: it doesn't put the readonly back after i click tab to the next input or when i click out of current input

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I'm struggling to see the point of this. If I get this right, you want the input field *not* to be editable until it is clicked or selected by the user (which is basically how input fields work anyhow: you can't change their value unless you select them). After these input fields loose their focus, they should go back to being read only. 
If this is the case, you're over complicating things. However, that is none of my business. The best way to get this done IMO, is by delegating the event.

I therefore put together a couple of fiddles, on pure JS, on jQuery. Both are far from perfect, but should help you on your way.

Regular JS ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yHv8Z/)):

```
var dv = document.getElementById('inputDiv');
if (!dv.addEventListener)
{
    dv.attachEvent('onfocusin',switchRO);
    dv.attachEvent('onfocusout',switchRO);
}
else
{
    dv.addEventListener('focus',switchRO,true);
    dv.addEventListener('blur',switchRO,true);
}

function switchRO (e)
{
    var self;
    e = e || window.event;
    self = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (self.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input')
    {
        switch (e.type)
        {
            case 'onfocusin':
            case 'focus':
                self.removeAttribute('readonly');
            break;
            default:
                self.setAttribute('readonly','readonly');
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In jQuery, this might look something like this (jQuery with `.on`, [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/arN3b/)):

```
$('#inputDiv input').on(
    {
        focus: function()
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
        },
        blur: function()
        {
            $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
        }
    });
```

​
I posted both jQuery and pure JS, because I find it both informative and educational to know what goes on behind the screens in jQuery.